# How to count specific strings in file?

Tags: shell-script

Using hash table to count specific strings, and out put a result with time it repeat.

File A

```
AAA
BBB
CCC
DDD
BBB
DDD
AAA
CCC
BBB
AAA
BBB
CCC
BBB
```

Result

```
AAA 3
BBB 5
CCC 3
DDD 2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this homework? If not, just use `sort` and `uniq`:

```
$ sort file | uniq -c
  3 AAA
  5 BBB
  3 CCC
  2 DDD
```

If you need to script it yourself for some reason, you could use Perl:

```
$ perl -lne '$k{$_}++; END{print "$_\t$k{$_}" for keys(%k)}'
CCC 3
BBB 5
DDD 2
AAA 3
```

If you really need to use a shell script, you could do (here `bash` or `ksh` syntax):

```
unset num;
typeset -A num; 
while IFS= read -r line; do 
  ((num[$line]++))
done < file
for line in "${!num[@]}"; do 
  printf '%s\t%s\n' "$line" "${num[$line]}"
done
```

Comment: No need for `chomp` with `-l`.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas indeed, thanks. It was left over from a first version that did not use `-l`. And thanks for the edit, an improvement, as usual.

Comment: @terdon thanks for wonderful answer. a lots things to learn

Answer (score 3):

With awk:

```
awk  '{count[$1]++} END {for (string in count) { print string ":" count[string]}}' data
```

where `data` is the name of your file

Answer (score -2):

Another possibility is

```
cat file | sort | uniq | wc -l
```

Comment: `wc -l` counts total lines in the file, it does not count total occurrences of unique strings.

Comment: true, now it should be a valid answer

Comment: not quite, `cat file | sort | uniq | wc -l` will tell you the number of unique strings in the file, not the number of occurrences of each unique string.  Also, `cat` is useless in this context as you can begin the pipeline with `sort file`. The right answer is `sort file | uniq -c` which you can see in the A by terdon.

Comment: 'uniq | wc -l' is not as precise as 'uniq -c'. Might prefer that output.